# Add more than 2 different views in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is it possible to add more than 2 views in a viewpager ?
I add this code to Main.class:

```
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

AdapterPage adapterPage = new AdapterPage();

adapterPage.insertViewId(R.id.page_one);
adapterPage.insertViewId(R.id.page_two);
adapterPage.insertViewId(R.id.page_three);

viewPager.setAdapter(adapterPage);
```

PagerAdapter class:

```
public class AdapterPage extends PagerAdapter {
    private List<Integer> pageIds = new ArrayList<>();

    public void insertViewId(@IdRes int pageId) {
        pageIds.add(pageId);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        return container.findViewById(pageIds.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}
```

xml :

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="500dp">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/page_one"
                        layout="@layout/detail1" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/page_two"
                        layout="@layout/detail2" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/page_three"
                        layout="@layout/detail3" />

                </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

This codes works but the problem is..

1. When I slide/swipe to the last page named **page_three / detail3 layout** (in this case I add 3 different layouts), it took longer time to load the layout.
2. When I slide/swipe back to the first page / **page_one**, the layout dissapeared.

Is there any library or other view for this case ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try inflating each page in `instantiateItem` depending on the `position`. ViewPager only saves the pages n+1 and n-1 to where n is the actual page, thats why your 3rd page always disappears.